# Understanding Magento Adminhtml Layouts

Tags: magento

I am trying to load a custom layout page for my custom admin page "devices". Its not working ! :)

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <adminhtml_devices_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/template" name="index" output="toHtml" template="devices/index.phtml"/>
    </reference>
   </adminhtml_devices_index_index>
</layout>
```

If this is the XML in my app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/devices.xml

What are the different files/attributes I must be aware of ?

Also, what does type='adminhtml/template' actually point to ?

Note: My Controller code is

```
public function indexAction() {
  $this->loadLayout();
  $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Comment: Also, I am not sure, if this layout specification is correct. As magento does not tell me if there is anything wrong with it.

Comment: How are you diagnosing that layout is not loaded?

Comment: I have included alanstorms showConfig and showLayout modules. When I try a showConfig=true I do not see any of my layout specifications in that config and neither when I try a showLayout=page/handles

Answer (score 1):

For a quick test, use a non-template block. The block is going to be output as a course of rendering in the "content" block, so no need to specify `output="toHtml"`.

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/text" name="devices.test">
        <action method="setText">
            <val>This is some sample text</val>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

The block type argument `adminhtml/template` points to the block class group "adminhtml", which is defined in `Mage_Adminhtml` config.xml:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <class>Mage_Adminhtml_Block
```

Based on this, the `adminhtml/template` argument points to the block name `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <devices_adminhtml_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/template" name="index" output="toHtml" template="devices/index.phtml"/>
    </reference>
   </devices_adminhtml_index_index>
</layout>
```

And I not sure what here should be: `adminhtml/template` Try replace it with `core/template`

Comment: nope ! did it seem to work. How should "devices_adminhtml_index_index" be understood ?

Comment: It's a layout update handle. it is constructed from your router configuration node + controller file path (index) + action name (index). If you are adding your router configuration in `admin > routers > adminhtml > args > modules` then you will use adminhtml as your router configuration node.

Comment: See, Adminhtml_ - it is module name like Catalog/ or Customer. You can see controllers in Mage/Adminhtml - it is simple group of controllers just one module. If you has wrote adminhtml into layout then Magento will find modules into this module. But you can write `devices_index_index` thus you should create controller XXX_Modulename_DevicesController without the "_Adminhtml_" piece of name but it not recommend for more clarity.

Comment: Hmmm. I see. When I say name="content" I am guessing this will be a reference only to the content area of my template ? What if, I want only the template that I specify to show up, and not the default adminhtml header (menu, logo, etc) ?

Comment: Not at all. If you will specify `content` other blocks (header, footer etc) will be inherited from parent blocks. If you need page without header then write into layout: `<remove name="header">`. Or you can overwrite base template for needed pages (your or system).

Comment: I see. My config is of the path config > admin > routers > device. So my layout handle should be "device_index_index" and my controller being Company_Device_IndexController. Is this right ?